# R Forecasting with covariates MARSS package

Tags: r, forecasting, state-space

I've written a model with the MARSS package for R.

The main idea behind the model is to forecast the observable vector for at least 10 quarters, however I can't seem to do it using the MARSSsimulate function (I believe it is because of the inclussion the exogenous vector, named season, in the estimation process). I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

The dataset can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/a/unal.edu.co/file/d/0B-ejtE0JwRcdTFhCcUp1ajNteHc/view?usp=sharing)

I've used the following code

```
info        <- read.table("series_kalman2.txt",header=T,dec=".")
dat_est_spa <- t(info[,3:6])

Sigma <-  sqrt(apply(dat_est_spa, 1, var, na.rm=TRUE))
y.bar <-  apply(dat_est_spa, 1, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
dat.z <-  (dat_est_spa - y.bar) * (1/Sigma)
rownames(dat.z) = rownames(dat_est_spa)

N.ts <- dim(dat_est_spa)[1]

season <- rbind(rep(c(1,0,0,0),ceiling(dim(dat_est_spa)[2]/4)), 
                rep(c(0,1,0,0),ceiling(dim(dat_est_spa)[2]/4)), 
                rep(c(0,0,1,0),ceiling(dim(dat_est_spa)[2]/4)),
                rep(c(0,0,0,1),ceiling(dim(dat_est_spa)[2]/4)))

rownames(season) <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")

season <- season[,-((dim(dat_est_spa)[2]+1):dim(season)[2])]

### Model

cntl.list = list(minit=200, maxit=60000, allow.degen=FALSE)
mod_est_spa   <- list(A="zero", R="diagonal and equal", m=3)
estim_est_spa <- MARSS(dat.z, model=mod_est_spa, control=cntl.list, 
                       form="dfa", covariates=season)

### Forecast

MARSSsimulate(estim_est_spa, tSteps = 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot download the data file from the linked site as it says "permission denied".

Anyway, you are correct in that the inclusion of the `season` covariate will preclude the use of `MARSSsimulate()`, but you do have another option that comes with a large caveat.

You are fitting a DFA model with 3 latent trends, which themselves are merely unbiased random walks. Therefore, you could easily simulate the random walks by drawing innovations from a multivariate normal with mean vector

`mu = matrix(0, m, 1)`

and variance-covariance matrix

`Sigma = coef(estim_est_spa, "matrix")$Q`.

You can get the estimated states for the last time step **T**, which would be the starting place for your forecasted states by

`X_T = estim_est_spa$states[,dim(dat_est_spa)[2]]`.

The loadings are

`Z = coef(estim_est_spa, "matrix")$Q`,

which would need to be rotated. See the DFA example in the [MARSS User's Guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MARSS/vignettes/UserGuide.pdf) for the matrix math.

Note, however, that forecasting with a DFA model is not likely to be very promising because the latent trends are random walks, which generally make very bad forecast models.